# Telerik RadGrid ExportToExcel not working

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a radgrid and I want to use the built-in functionality to export the data in the grid to a spreadsheet.  I remember a time when I ran the code and it worked, but right now when the call is made, nothing happens.

Anyone experience this problem or have any suggestions?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest posting this question in the [Telerik Forums](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums.aspx) or checking out the code in the [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/exporting/defaultcs.aspx).

Please include at least some of your code unless you want people to just guess at what might be wrong. My first guess would be that you are binding manually to the radgrid with a dataset or datatable and are not binding the data before trying to export.